# Shoter time_ago_in_words eg. 1d ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my design i have a latest posts block, in this block there is very little space to say when the post was posted. Therefore, I did it as "1d" instead of "1 day ago". I would like it to be either "Today", "Yesterday" or "xd"(1d, 2d, 3d, etc)

The main reason for not using hours and minutes(and seconds..) is that my format is like this posted_date="2013-01-04", so no hours, minutes, seconds etc.

Is this posible?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck?

Comment: If `1 day ago` is represented as `"Yesterday"`, then when does `1d` appear, and what does it mean? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def days_ago(date)
  days = ((Time.now - date) / 24 / 60 / 60).round

  case days
  when 0    then 'Today'
  when 1    then 'Yesterday'
  else           "#{days}d"
  end
end
```

Comment: Since `date` is an instance of `Date`, you could avoid the calculation with `case date` and `when Date.today ...`, `when Date.yesterday ...`

Comment: But you will new the calculated `days` for the `else` case anyway.

Comment: The problem is that i do not have a proper date format, but a string like this "2013-01-04"

Comment: @OlufNielsen either use `Date.parse("2013-01-04")` or refactor your code